# Unpacking first parameter from template parameter pack c++

Tags: c++, templates, parameter-pack

I'm new with templates, specially with parameter pack and I wonder if I can get the first value from the pack.

For example the following code:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
bool register(Args... args) {
    if (!Foo<T>(args..) {
        assert(std::is_same_v<std::string, args...[0]>);
        std::cerr << "Failed call Foo with " + args...[0] + "\n";
    }
}
```

How do I really get the first value in `args...`?

Worth to note that `args..`. can contain different types (string, boolean, etc.)

Comment: Is there something that's preventing you from trying it out yourself, and seeing whether this is the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use lambda to extract the first parameter:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
bool register(Args... args) {
  if (!Foo<T>(args...)) {
    auto& first = [](auto& first, auto&...) -> auto& { return first; }(args...);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::string,
                                 std::remove_reference_t<decltype(first)>>);
    std::cerr << "Failed call Foo with " + first + "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: I meant *"non-POD class types are conditionally-supported"* ([cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments#Default_conversions)). it might produce [warning for msvc C4839](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-GB/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-3-c4839) or even compile error [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/v589M584T). using template (`auto& first, auto&&...`) instead of C-ellipsis (`auto& first, ...`) to have full control.

Comment: @Jarod42 Ouch, I've got your point, that is indeed a potential problem, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Simpler in your case seems to change your function into:

```
template <typename T, typename Arg, typename... Args>
bool register(Arg arg, Args... args) {
    if (!Foo<T>(arg, args...) {
        assert(std::is_same_v<std::string, Arg>);
        std::cerr << "Failed call Foo with " + arg + "\n";
    }
}
```

and from the assert, even

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
bool register(const std::string& s, Args... args) {
    if (!Foo<T>(s, args...) {
        std::cerr << "Failed call Foo with " + s + "\n";
    }
}
```

else [`<tuple>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/tuple) provides some useful tools:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
bool register(Args... args) {
    if (!Foo<T>(args...) {
        assert(std::is_same_v<std::string,
                              std::tuple_element_t<0, std::tuple<Args...>>);
        std::cerr << "Failed call Foo with "
            + std::get<0>(std::tie(args...)) + "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I normally use the solution described above, just add an explicit extra template parameter for the first parameter. If you cannot do that this also works :

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace details
{
    template<typename type_t, typename... args_t>
    struct deduce_first
    {
        using type = type_t;
    };
}

template<typename... args_t>
using first_t = typename details::deduce_first<args_t...>::type;

template<typename... args_t>
bool register_f(args_t&&... args)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<first_t<args_t...>, bool>, "first argument should have type bool");
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    register_f(true, 1.0);
    // register_f(1.0); <== does indeed not complie

    return 0;
}
```